# Оценка скорости работы алгоритма.

Tags: c++, алгоритм, производительность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой скоростью будет работать этот алгоритм? Алгоритм считает суммы предшествующих элементов массива. **Справедлива ли для этого алгоритма оценка O(n)?**
Псевдокод:

```
Функ(A[...], n)    {A - массив, нумерация начинается с 1, n - длина массива}   
    i <- 2    
    Пока i <= n: {Начало цикла 1}
        A[i] <- A[i] + A[i-1]
        i <- i + 1
    {Конец цикла 1}
```

C++:

```
void funk1(int *mass, int len){
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        mass[i] += mass[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разберём.

За каждую итерацию цикла выполняется 7 операций: вычитание единицы, два индексирования, два чтения, одно сложение и одна запись. Расход на управление циклом — одна проверка и одно увеличение счётчика на итерацию, ну ещё один переход. Итого 10 операций на итерацию.

Сколько всего итераций? Очевидно, `n - 1` (или `len - 1` в вашей C++-записи). Плюс ещё операция на инициализацию переменной. Итого `10 * n - 10 + 1` = `10 * n - 9`.

Является ли `10 * n - 9` O(n), вы должны знать сами.

---

Да, я знаю, что подсчёт не вполне корректен, т. к. оптимизатор может вмешаться и улучшить код, сложения могут стоить дороже, разные операции отображаются на разное число циклов процессора и т. д. Но это повлияет лишь на коэффициент при `n`.